# One-hand or One-handed?

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

I often see **two-handed** used with weapons. But have never seen **two-hand**.

However, with a weapon that needs only one hand I've met both **one-hand** and **one-handed**.

Are they both correct?

Comment: The most common noun after ***two-handed*** is ***sword*** (***weapon, broadsword*** and ***rod*** are also common), so it's closely associated with that specific sub-sense (as opposed to, say, [*a two-handed **game***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/two-handed)). We don't often need to *explicitly* say that something can be held/used with one hand (by default, we assume practically everything manipulable is capable of being hefted with one hand). So for your *very specific* context you should probably just mimic the established ***two-handed*** and go for ***one-handed***.

Comment: It might seem irrelevant with *one-hand[ed] weapon*, but it gets messy with *one-hand gun* - especially in a *spoken* context, where everyone would tend to hear it as ***one handgun***.

Comment: Judging by the movie clips I've seen, it's possible to launch a nuclear-armed ballistic missile with just one hand - although I've not seen them referred to as one-handed missiles.

Answer (score 1):

"Hand" and "handed" have two distinct meanings.

- You can use the word "hand" by itself, when speaking about a hand that is doing nothing.
- "Handed" specifically denotes an action involved, ie *doing something one-handed.*

You can describe a weapon as "a one-hand weapon" or "a one-handed weapon" because the first describes the design of the weapon (it fits in one hand) and the second describes the way that it is used (it can be fired with one hand).

You can't say "two hand" in the same way, because it would be "two hand**s**". And I would suggest this is why you do not hear a weapon, or anything else correctly described that way.

Comment: What about duel-hand?

Comment: @SovereignSun Are you confusing "duel" with "dual"?

Comment: My phone is, in fact, yes. 'Dual-hand' it is, indeed.

Comment: @SovereignSun "Dual-hand" is acceptable because it can mean "either" as well as "both". For example "dual-purpose" can mean something does two things, not necessarily at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> Definition of one–handed [MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one-handed)
>
> - 1 :  having or using only one hand could beat him up one–handed
> - 2 a :  designed for or requiring the use of only one hand
> - 2 b :  effected by the use of only one hand

So it is defined in the dictionary. I've heard "He caught it one-handed."

Comment: Would a composition for piano four-hands be considered four-handed?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Sorry, I do not know.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo No, it would be described as a "duet" - two people. When you think about it, most things are only noteworthy if they are one-handed, as most people have two hands. If I told you I rode my bike one-handed, that is remarkable. It would be redundant to say I rode it two-handed, as that is the correct way to ride a bike.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo After some time, the right answer is 'piano piece for four hands'